# PEAR install problems

Tags: php, download, batch-file, installation, pear

Having spent the last 5 hours trying to install PEAR I'm somewhat at a loss for what to try next. The initial go-pear.phar running from the command line produces the following error:

[image: http://imgur.com/iHKSZ]

I can install the PEAR files from the package, but this doesn't include the pear.bat file and other registration files. I can't use the web installer because it puts the package manager in my www directory, and if I try moving the files the path variables all fail to work again. I've searched Google for ages and nowhere can you download the files on their own- everything is just circular references getting back to go-pear.phar, which does not work. I've tried using older PHP versions (5.2.9) without effect.

The system is running through EasyPHP on Windows 7 64 bit, account is a single account administrator, UAC is disabled. Can someone zip up the PEAR files and host them somewhere so that I can get hold of them to install manually, as this would be the quickest way to solve the issues?

Comment: do you have permissions to use file manipulation functions (like mkdir) for the user PHP runs under? Your using windows, I would not know how to check this there...

Comment: As far as I know I have all necessary permissions. I have now finally managed to resolve this issue by finding someone with a working PEAR install and having them email the various packages over - I've now compiled a single PEAR install tar and am going to write an NSIS script to act as an installer for registry and Environment variables to make the process much simpler in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from my comment (so I can accept it): I finally managed to resolve this issue by finding someone with a working PEAR install and having them email the various packages over - I've now compiled a single PEAR install tar.

Since this question (over a year ago I've done multiple PEAR installs on different machines without issue - guess this was just a few bad downloads!

Answer (score 1):

PEAR 1.9.4 has just been released. Get a new phar and try it again.